# Percentage or Pixels: What to use on widths and heights

Tags: html, css, web

So I need professional opinion about this. This has been my dilemma for a long time now because I'm worried that if I used pixels in a width of let's say a `<div>` then I think it would look different depending on the screen resolution of the monitor. That's why I always used percentage in widths since when for example, I assign 90% width for div, CSS would be able to adjust it to the screen resolution.

Is my logic correct about using percentage and pixels? Please help me on this one thanks!

Comment: the layout of what are you referring to? It differs for different situations.

Comment: _'So I need professional opinion about this.'_ Please do not pose open-ended questions that involve opinion or discussion rather than a straight technical answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 1):

I think your strategy is very sensible. When developing for more than one monitor size/device it's probably for the best to use percentages. However, you need to make sure that you do everything one way or the other, else some interesting (but not functional) results can appear. Sometimes if you are developing for a really small screen, however, it can be best to have a seperate stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

No, your logic is not really correct. It all depends on your layout. If you create a layout with fixed dimensions(pixel) then the sizes of the layout will not change when the screen-size (or window-size) changes. In such a layout you can use pixel and percentage for the inner elements, depending on what you can works best with.

When you have a fluid layout (percentage) then the layout changes it's dimensions with a changing screen-size. In this type of layout you use mostly % for the inner elements and perhaps some pixel-sizes on carefully chosen elements.